# How do I re-use my wildcard match?

Tags: windows, cmd, wildcard

There's some advanced file moving that needs to be done with the Windows command prompt; Is it possible to do it with wildcards?

Using regular expressions in UNIX, I could do something like this to find all files that begin with "s" and then do something else with them (echo).

```
ls s(.*) ; echo Found file \1 , needs to be moved to C:\unicorns\(\1)
```

I want to do something like that in Windows command prompt:

```
:: find all files that begin with "s" and then do something else with them (echo)
dir s(*) ; echo Found file \1
```

Comment: Related to Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143039/batch-script-to-move-specific-subfolders-to-new-parent-folder-based-on-current-p/31144592#31144592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
for %%f in (*) do (echo %%f)
```

This will echo a list of files found in current directory.
Find more description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file)